# weight painting ruins the form

Tags: weight-painting

My first time weight painting after rigging.

When I do that, I wanted to color it red, but as I color on the object,

the form changes like sculpting. For example, it suddenly protrudes or deepen.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to select your mesh then armature using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+RightClick then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then choose `parent with automatic weighting`. This will save you time painting everything manually.